# Why reference variables is used to access class member inside main function when main is the part of that class

Tags: java

main function is part of the class therefore we should be able to access root as it is instead of tree.root after creating an object of the class, as instance variables are accessed using this variable inside instance method?

````
class Main
{ 

    Node root; 
    Main() 
    { 
        root = null; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Main tree = new Main(); 

      //  tree.root = new Node(1); 
        } 
} ```
````

Comment: Do you know the difference between static and instance members of a class?

Comment: You should read up on 'static' vs 'instance'. In the main method, there is no instance of Main, so there is no root to be accessed. the main method can have several instances of the Main class, so which root should it take?

Comment: try to add in constroctore   Main(  Node root=null) 
    { 
        this.root = root; 
    }

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai how would that change anything? the root element would still have to be called from the instance of Main

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the non static class field from the `static` method no matter if it's `main` or another one - you need a reference to the object to know at what exactly `root` you are pointing, or you need a `static` field

The `static` method can be called even if no `Main` object was created yet - which `root` variable would you like to access in such situation?